# Calculating the top left corner in a 2d field

Tags: graphics, geometry, code-request

[image: Grid]

Given I have a field with several rectangles like shown in the picture.
A point with its x and y coordinates are given. The height(h) and the width(w) are also given. How can I calculate the top left corner with x, y h and w?

Comment: `pos + size/2` ?

Comment: hm doesn't work for my example

Comment: So your origin is the upper left hand corner?

Comment: Correct. The purpose is a 2d Game where the user clicks somewhere into the field and the program needs to put a thing to the top left corner of a square in a field of squares

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about middle-school level math; nothing to do with Mathematica.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to work in grid positions, e.g. *gridX × height* and *gridY × width* to come up with screen coordinates that have to be corrected by an *offset* to line up the grid-origin one is using with its true screen coordinates.

The position in the grid can be obtained by using [`Quotient`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quotient.html) thus returning the grid coordinates as integers.

In the given example the width of a box (assuming the red point is in the middle) is 200 and the height is 120 so the x-Axis confusingly here is the *ordinate* and the x-Axis the *abscissa*:

```
Clear[ leftCorner ];
leftCorner[ x_, y_, w_, h_ ] := With[
  {
      offset = {50, 80} (* needed to correct for true screen position *)
  }, 

  { Quotient[ x, h ], Quotient[  y, w ] } × {h, w} + offset

]

leftCorner[ 230, 180, (* w = *) 2 (180 - 80), (* h= *) 2 (230-170)  ]
```

> {170,80}

```
leftCorner[ 100, 100, 200, 120]
```

> {50,80}

So the origin of our implicit grid for calculations would be the left corner of the box above the marked one in the OP.

Comment: I have now changed *w* and *h* to match the OP exactly where the axis are confusingly given with *x-Axis* as ordinate and *y-Axis* as abscissa. This all of course had to be deduced from a somewhat sloppy graph...